# Regex to find words with one character diff

Tags: regex

I have a word dictionary and I'm looking for regex that can help me to get words with only one character diff. For example say for word **BIG** it could be words **BIT**, **BUG** etc. Length of the words should be equal.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think a single regex is the answer. You'll probably want to use regular expressions, but there is some logic you'll need to apply.

Answer (score 2):

```
/\b([a-z]ig|b[a-z]g|bi[a-z])\b/i
```

You'd have to do this with every word. Regex alone is probably not the best tool for this job.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this, perhaps?

```
>>> def word_difference(word1, word2):
...     c1, c2 = list(word1), list(word2)
...     return [(i, c1[i], c2[i]) for i in in range(len(c1)) if c1[i] != c2[i]]
>>> word_difference("foo", "bar")
[(0, 'f', 'b'), (1, 'o', 'a'), (2, 'o', 'r')]
>>> word_difference("big", "bug")
[(1, 'i', 'u')]
```

Obviously, the length of the list returned is the number of characters that are different. I assume this is what you want, since you didn't state whether the characters may be in different positions or not - but that's just as easy, you can use sets.

Answer (score 1):

I found nearly the same solution than the one using ideone.
But, as vkolodrevskiy wrote “to get words with only one character **diff**“,
I respected it.

My code is in Python. No language precised in the question.

```
import re

word = 'main'

RE = '|'.join(word[0:i]+'(?!'+char+')[a-z]'+word[i+1:] for i,char in enumerate(word))
RE = '('+RE+')'
print RE

ch = 'the main reason is pain due to rain. hello muin, where is maih ?'

print re.findall(RE,ch)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do a bunch of complicated regular expressions, or ingenius ones, but I found something that I wanted to tell you about that may be a lot easier.

Check out the Levenshtein module to get the hamming distance between two strings. Then just get the ones that have a distance of one.

To install you can use `pip install python-levenshtein`. If you use Ubuntu or such you can use `sudo apt-get install python-levenshtein`. If you're on Windows, in order to fully utilize pip you'll need a C++ compiler (like Visual C++ 2010 express, if you're using Python 3, or Visual C++ 2008 express for Python 2.x; you can download those for free from Microsoft; do a web search for them if you want them).

```
import Levenshtein #Note the capital L
help(Levenshtein) #See the documentation
Levenshtein.hamming("cat", "sat") #Returns 1; they must be the same length, as you specified
```

There are lots of other cool functions besides hamming, though. Read the help (via the help function in the code above). The functions are actually surprisingly well-documented if you use the help function. Press q to quit the help, of course.

Answer (score 0):

finally I did not use idea with regex, my solution looks like:

```
public boolean diffOneChar(String word1, String word2) {
    int diff=0;
    if(word1 == null || word2 == null) return false;
    if(word1.length() == 0 || word2.length() == 0) return false;
    if(word1.length() != word2.length()) return false;

    for(int i=0; i<word1.length(); i++) {
        if(word1.charAt(i)!=word2.charAt(i))
            diff++;
    }

    return diff == 1;
}
```